# What is used more commonly?

Tags: usage

Let's say that I want to say that I have just turned my pc off.

Which of these sentences is more commonly to be heard?

> 1. I have just turned my pc off.
> 2. I turned my pc off.

Comment: [correction: What is used more commonly?]

Comment: The word ***just*** here is a "quantifier / intensifier" - it just emphasizes that the action was ***very recent***. Note that there's also the position of the preposition - *I turned **off** my PC* and *I turned my PC **off*** are equally valid, and ***mean exactly the same thing*** (but with a pronoun you can only say *I turned **it off***, not *I turned **off it***).

Comment: Do I always have to use the word "have" before "just"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "I want to say that I have just turned my pc off."

You say "I have just turned my pc off."

If you wanted to say "I turned my pc off" then you would say "I turned my pc off".
The meanings are very similar and overlap so usually it doesn't matter what you say.  You could use "just" to emphasise that the event happen very recently.  It is common to use present perfect "I have just turned" but it is not required. "I just turned.." is correct English.